# uint32_t changes from 4 bytes to 6 bytes in linux

Tags: c++, c

i have this struct that is in theory 14 bytes

```
typedef struct ActionArgument{
 ManagedObjectId managed_object; 
 uint32_t scope1;                        
 OIDType action_type;            
 uint16_t length; } ActionArgument;
```

the struct ManagedObjectId is 6 bytes , scope is "suposedly" 4 bytes , OIDType is a uint16_t ( 2 bytes ) so is length.
But the problem is when i print the size of scope i get 4 bytes which is right , but the size of struct ActionArgument becomes 16. 
I tried to correct this by spliting scope to 2 uint16_t variables (scope1 and scope2) and it worked .
But i am still intrigued why the size of a uint23_t is 4 but when i put it in a struct it becomes 6? can some one explain to me ?

I am using kalilinux 4.14.0-kali3-amd64

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are aligned in memory, so there is a padding added between `ManagedObjectId` and `scope1`. One easy way to avoid the padding is to change the struct member order.

Comment: when i looked in the memory ,the 2 bytes padding are found between scope and action_type

Comment: Also i can't change the struct member order because it is a message that needs to be transmitted through UDP as is

Comment: @Dest `#pragma pack` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dest If you don't want to rely on compiler extensions, you'll have to manually put information into an array of bytes. The structure in memory of `structs` is not guaranteed. The endianess of the system will also affect the message.

Comment: thanks @Jesper Juhl , it was a padding problem made by the compiler , #pragma pack(1) just corrected it .Thanks again